# Custom Thumbnails

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create custom thumbnail dialogues for the homepage of my WordPress installation.

This is what I want to achieve:[image]

This is the bootstrap code for the image above:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>...</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So until now, I have the code below and I can't have the content in a single line.

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <?php // theloop
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>        

<?php// Define our WP Query Parameters ?>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' ); ?>

<?php// Start our WP Query ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>


<div class="thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100, 100)); ?>
<div class="caption">            
<?php// Display the Post Title with Hyperlink?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>


<?php// Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit
</div>    
</div>
</div>   
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

The screenshot below reflects the result of my current code (non-desirable):
[image]

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i fixed it. But thank you all anyway.

```
        <div class="row">   
          <h4>Noticias Recentes</h4>
          <?php // theloop
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


<?php// Define our WP Query Parameters ?>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' ); ?>

<?php// Start our WP Query ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">

<div class="thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100, 100)); ?>
<div class="caption">            
<?php// Display the Post Title with Hyperlink?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>



<!--// Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit-->
</div>    
</div>    
</div>  
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code it says: `the_post_thumbnail(array(100, 100));`. You are using [the function `the_post_thumbnail();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) to get an image of 100px*100px or as close to that as is present in the media library.

You could use a different image size i.e. `the_post_thumbnail('medium');`.

You could also [register a new image size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) closer to what you need.

Comment: That was not the answer for my question. But thank you anyway ;)